# How do I make the grid items fill the whole container without manually declaring their size?auto property doesn't seems to work

Tags: html, css

here is the html code

```
<body>
<div class="outlay">
    <div class="screen"></div>
    <div class="grid-outlay">
        <div class="num" id="1">1</div>
        <div class="num" id="2">2</div>
        <div class="num" id="3">3</div>
        <div class="num" id="4">4</div>
        <div class="num" id="5">5</div>
        <div class="num" id="6">6</div>
        <div class="num" id="7">7</div>
        <div class="num" id="8">8</div>
        <div class="num" id="9">9</div>
        <div class="num" id="0">0</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

This is the css code ,what is the most efficient way through which I can fit all the grids in the .outlay container without any gaps

```
    .grid-outlay{
         display:grid;
         grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
         grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
     }
    .num{
    background-color:orange;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content:center;
     }
```

Comment: put your html as well or a working code will be better, and how many columns and rows you want or it will be increasing or decreasing?

Comment: I want 3 rows and 4 columns and no they wont be increasing or decreasing

Answer (score 0):

This is easy in this case when these numbers are not changing, try this.

```css
.grid-outlay {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 33.33vh 33.33vh 33.33vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="outlay">
    <div class="screen"></div>
    <div class="grid-outlay">
        <div class="num" id="1">1</div>
        <div class="num" id="2">2</div>
        <div class="num" id="3">3</div>
        <div class="num" id="4">4</div>
        <div class="num" id="5">5</div>
        <div class="num" id="6">6</div>
        <div class="num" id="7">7</div>
        <div class="num" id="8">8</div>
        <div class="num" id="9">9</div>
        <div class="num" id="0">0</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```